# Why is the `sll` query parameter for a Maps URL being (sort of) ignored?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

According to [various](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) [references](http://seizetruth.com/Tech/GoogleMaps/#Google_Maps_URL_Parameters), Google Maps has a query param called `sll` which does the following:

> Latitude,longitude of the point from which the business search
>   should be performed. You could use this to perform an off-centre
>   busness search. Google use it so "link to this page" can record a map
>   that has had the centre moved after performing a business search. When
>   requesting a route
>   `map.getBounds().getSouthWest().toUrlValue()` returns the
>   same value maps.google.com uses.

So, for instance, if `(43.464258, -80.52041)` happens to be in Waterloo, Ontario, and  `(42.24370, -82.98320)` happens to be in Windsor, Ontario (many hundreds of kilometers away), then my interpretation of the above documentation would be that the following query:

```
https://maps.google.ca/maps?saddr=43.464258,-80.52041&daddr=mcdonalds&sll=42.24370,-82.98320
```

will do a search for "Mcdonalds" **from** Waterloo, **to** some McDonald's in Windsor.

Unfortunately, that's not what happens ([click for yourself](https://maps.google.ca/maps?saddr=43.464258,-80.52041&daddr=mcdonalds&sll=42.24370,-82.98320) to see!). It ends up doing a search from the `saddr` point, to the nearest McDonald's *to that point*. The value of `sll` doesn't factor into it at all.

But here's where it gets weird! If I **[omit](https://maps.google.ca/maps?saddr=43.464258,-80.52041&daddr=mcdonalds)** the `sll` parameter entirely, then Maps does something completely unexpected: it picks some random McDonald's in Toronto (a city that is many kilometers away from either Waterloo *or* Windsor). I need to add some `sll` parameter (for any value) to make Maps return a result in Waterloo (even though what I'm asking for is a result in Windsor).

Am I misinterpreting all the various sources of documentation about this parameter? Is this a bug on Maps' end? And, most importantly, is there any working way to do what I'm trying to do, even if it doesn't involve the `sll` parameter at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get it to work with a simple query :

> [from:43.464258,-80.52041 to:mcdonalds near 42.24370,-82.98320](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=from:43.464258,-80.52041%20to%3amcdonalds%20near%2042.24370,%20-82.98320)

Which gives the expected result. It won't work without `near` which is a keyword.

You can also search [`from:43.464258,-80.52041 to:mcdonalds, Windsor`](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=from:43.464258,-80.52041%20to%3amcdonalds,%20Windsor) if you have the city name.

About the `sll` (and `sspn`) parameters, it doesn't work for directions AFAIK. It only works with searches for a single location.